# Gulp File Task never defined: licenses

Tags: gulp, netlify

I am trying to deploy my react app on netlify and the log gives me this error.

[image]

Belowe here is the gulpfile ,  Anyone knows why this error occurs? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the task() API is not recommended any more.
Try to export your tasks instead. https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks